# E-mails with attachment issue

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I'm not an experienced programmer. I'm trying to use this code to get values from a html form with an attachment and email them to client. The code works fine on my demo server and mail is sending with the attachment. But the form freezes when I click the submit in clients server.

[Script source with form](http://reusableforms.com/d/a/html-email-form-with-attachment)

```
<?php
namespace FormGuide\Handlx;
use FormGuide\PHPFormValidator\FormValidator;
use PHPMailer;
use FormGuide\Handlx\Microtemplate;
use Gregwar\Captcha\CaptchaBuilder;

class FormHandler
{
    private $emails;
    public $validator;
    private $mailer;
    private $mail_template;
    private $captcha;
    private $attachments;
    private $recaptcha;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = array();
        $this->validator = FormValidator::create();
        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer;
        $this->mail_template='';

        $this->mailer->IsSMTP();
        $this->mailer->CharSet="UTF-8";
        $this->mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this->mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $this->mailer->Port = 587;
        $this->mailer->Username = 'ceilaoezy@gmail.com';
        $this->mailer->Password = 'hahadonttrythis';
        $this->mailer->SMTPAuth = true;

        $this->mailer->Subject = "Contact Form Submission ";

        $host = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])?$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']:'localhost';
        $from_email ='forms@'.$host;
        $this->mailer->setFrom($from_email,'Contact Form',false);  

        $this->captcha = false;   

        $this->attachments = [];

        $this->recaptcha =null;


    }

    /**
     * sendEmailTo: add a recipient email address
     * @param  string/array $email_s one or more emails. If more than one emails, pass the emails as array
     * @return The form handler object itself so that the methods can be chained
     */
    public function sendEmailTo($email_s)
    {
        if(is_array($email_s))
        {
            $this->emails =array_merge($this->emails, $email_s);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->emails[] = $email_s; 
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function useMailTemplate($templ_path)
    {
        $this->mail_template = $templ_path;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * [attachFiles find the file uplods and attach to the email]
     * @param  array $fields The array of field names
      */
    public function attachFiles($fields)
    {
        $this->attachments = array_merge($this->attachments, $fields);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getRecipients()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }

    /**
     * [validate add Validations. This function takes a call back function which receives the PHPFormValidator object]
     * @param  function $validator_fn The funtion gets a validator parameter using which, you can add validations 
     */
    public function validate($validator_fn)
    {
        $validator_fn($this->validator);
        return $this;
    }

    public function requireReCaptcha($config_fn=null)
    {
        $this->recaptcha = new ReCaptchaValidator();
        $this->recaptcha->enable(true);
        if($config_fn)
        {
            $config_fn($this->recaptcha);   
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function getReCaptcha()
    {
        return $this->recaptcha;
    }

    public function requireCaptcha($enable=true)
    {
        $this->captcha = $enable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidator()
    {
        return $this->validator;
    }

    public function configMailer($mailconfig_fn)
    {
        $mailconfig_fn($this->mailer);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMailer()
    {
        return $this->mailer;
    }

    public static function create()
    {
        return new FormHandler();
    }

    public function process($post_data)
    {
        if($this->captcha === true)
        {
            $res = $this->validate_captcha($post_data);
            if($res !== true)
            {
                return $res;
            }
        }
        if($this->recaptcha !== null &&
           $this->recaptcha->isEnabled())
        {
            if($this->recaptcha->validate() !== true)
            {
                return json_encode([
                'result'=>'recaptcha_validation_failed',
                'errors'=>['captcha'=>'ReCaptcha Validation Failed.']
                ]);
            }
        }

        $this->validator->test($post_data);

        //if(false == $this->validator->test($post_data))
        if($this->validator->hasErrors())
        {
            return json_encode([
                'result'=>'validation_failed',
                'errors'=>$this->validator->getErrors(/*associative*/ true)
                ]);
        }

        if(!empty($this->emails))
        {
            foreach($this->emails as $email)
            {
                $this->mailer->addAddress($email);
            }
            $this->compose_mail($post_data);

            if(!empty($this->attachments))
            {
                $this->attach_files();
            }

            if(!$this->mailer->send())
            {
                return json_encode([
                    'result'=>'error_sending_email',
                    'errors'=> ['mail'=> $this->mailer->ErrorInfo]
                    ]);         
            }
        }

        return json_encode(['result'=>'success']);
    }

    private function validate_captcha($post)
    {
        @session_start();
        if(empty($post['captcha']))
        {
            return json_encode([
                        'result'=>'captcha_error',
                        'errors'=>['captcha'=>'Captcha code not entered']
                        ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $usercaptcha = trim($post['captcha']);

            if($_SESSION['user_phrase'] !== $usercaptcha)
            {
                return json_encode([
                        'result'=>'captcha_error',
                        'errors'=>['captcha'=>'Captcha code does not match']
                        ]);     
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private function attach_files()
    {

        foreach($this->attachments as $file_field)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($file_field, $_FILES))
            {
                continue;
            }
            $filename = $_FILES[$file_field]['name'];

            $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($filename));

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], 
                $uploadfile))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $this->mailer->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        }
    }

    private function compose_mail($post)
    {
        $content = "Form submission: \n\n";
        foreach($post as $name=>$value)
        {
            $content .= ucwords($name).":\n";
            $content .= "$value\n\n";
        }
        $this->mailer->Body  = $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: use ssl in place of tls